# YouTube data API change video id

Tags: youtube-api

I need to change video I'd, so the URL got changed. Is it possible? As far as I can see from docs - its not supported... So is there any other way to change video URL programmatically?

Example:
When I uploaded video i received URL: youtube.com/watch?v=EMSGJdnDN8U Now (next day) I want to keep uploaded video on server, but i don't want URL youtube.com/watch?v=EMSGJdnDN8U to be available anymore, but the original video should be available on youtube.com/watch?=nEwUrL100500 (new url) and so on... 
Of course I know that i can reupload video and delete original one but i dont like that solution.

Comment: Hey buddy!! Welcome to stackoverflow. You might want to read about how you ask a question on this website. What you're asking is kinda vague and as far as I know imposible. I don't understand what you mean by you need to change the video ID?

Comment: Ok, let's see we have url: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EMSGJdnDN8U where EMSGJdnDN8U is video id, I need to dynamically change it, so all the related links (like https://www.youtube.com/embed/EMSGJdnDN8U) got changed as well...
I have read docs and where were nothing about it, so i've decided to ask YouTube devs, maybe i'm missing something...

Comment: In what language and framework do you want to do this? Because you can replace a string or video in a couple of elements or reload objects.

Comment: php (yii2) or js (vue.js)
but i don't need to change them in player, i need to change it on youTube

I need to change video URL from  youtube.com/watch?v=EMSGJdnDN8U to something like  youtube.com/watch?=nEwUrL100500

Comment: Do you need to change this onload of a page or when the page is still active?

Comment: Let's clearfy: i dont' need to change video url in player
I need to change it on youtube server, eg.
When I uploaded video i received URL: youtube.com/watch?v=EMSGJdnDN8U
Now (next day) I want to keep uploaded video on server, but i don't want URL youtube.com/watch?v=EMSGJdnDN8U to be available anymore, but the original video should be available on youtube.com/watch?=nEwUrL100500 (new url) and so on...
Of course I know that i can reupload video and delete original one but i dont like that solution

Comment: Well if you put all this information in your question people will read it and you might get another awnser. I don't think it's posible but maybe someone has an idea. But may I suggest to you that you alter your question with all this information so someone only needs to read the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I don’t think so. The video id is a very important identifier for YouTube and it’s very unlikely that they give you control over it.